# jquery image load function not being called properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load, pageshow

I am having the following issue in a mobile web application I am developing:  In javascript, I have a Image() control and I have an event attached to the image control that should fire when the image gets loaded.  Inside of the "pageshow" event for the page, I am setting the src attribute of the Image() to a valid image.  If I return to the page, after having visited the page once, the load event for the image is not firing.  I have seen several threads say that this can be caused by the image being cached but in my case I am pretty sure that is not the issue.  Why doesn't the load event for the image fire and how can I make it work properly?

Code follows:

```
<script>
var srcImage = new Image();
$(srcImage).on("load", function() {
 ...
});
$(document).one("pageshow", '#pageid', function () {
 srcImage.src = imagepath;
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Is the error handler being triggered?

Comment: Can you briefly explain or show how to set up an error handler for the above code?

Comment: `srcImage.onerror = function() { alert(this.src); };`

Comment: Yes the error handler was being triggered.  The image file was not valid.  I found and fixed the issue and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, thanks to epascarello (see above comments).  I assumed the image file was valid but discovered it was not.  When a valid image file is used, the above code works fine.